# Jsoup on Android : Follow redirection with Javascript (window.location)

Tags: android, redirect, jsoup

On my Android application, I'm using JSOUP to POST data to simulate a submit action for a login form (automatic log-in to a WISPR hotspot)
This is the raw Response that I get from the POST :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://
www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="fr" lang="fr">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>connexion</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                    window.location = "http://192.168.2.1:3990/logon?username=0325767676@ssowifi.neuf.fr&amp;response=e30ee504ba06fa77502f1b9e8ccbaf8d&amp;uamip=192.168.2.1&userurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sfr.fr%3Bneuf%3Bfr%3B3%3Bhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.sfr.fr%3B";
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

I compared it with the response that I get with a desktop browser using Firebug when login is successful and it's exactly the same, except of course the 'response' param.

As you can see, here, it uses Javascript for redirection.
As JSOUP only follows 3xx redirection, I tried to parse the given Location URL from the response and execute afterwards a GET request on it

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(parsedRedirectURL).cookies(cookies).get();
```

but I'm getting an

`Java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /192.168.2.1 (port 3390) after 3000ms`

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `window.location` says `:3990` and your exception `3390`. Are those parameters from two invocations so the port might have changed? Else check, if you indeed use the right port.

Comment: Yep, it was the port number that got messed up the second time, but I fixed it and it now works  ! Thank you very much for noticing it !